# oracle databse PSU , CPU release number

Tags: oracle, release, patch

I am currently working on oracle databases, but I don't have Oracle support. Anyone knows where to get a map of versions releases and CPU , CPU:
Example: 12.2.0.2.19XXXXX -- PSUJAN20XX ;
11.1.X.X.XXXXXXX -- CPUOCT2013

Answer (score 0):

Version release info is available here:

- https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/742060_1.html
- http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lsp-tech-chart-069290.pdf

Patch updates are cumulative and released quarterly, and Oracle has changed their branding a couple of times, so how they are described can be version or date-specific. See here: https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/patch-numbering-for-oracle-db,-enterprise-manager-and-middleware